# Caliburn micro wpf multiple projects

Tags: wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I want to start breaking my quickly growing projects up into more modular/smaller pieces.  How would you go about breaking your views/viewmodels up into other projects, sometimes not even knowing who is tapped into the events/messaging/conductor pipeline until runtime?

At minimum, I just need to organize my view/viewmodels more eloquently, at most I would love to take the MEF + Caliburn Micro + WPF party to the next level with some modularity.

So, any ideas how I get started?  Some talk of overriding the create in appbootstrapper but the examples all seem pre MEF.

-J

Comment: please see my answer. A complete Bootstrapper leveraging MEF is included in the tutorial that is linked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already seen that Tutorial on caliburn.micro?

[Mindscape "caliburn.micro getting started"](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/)

In Chapter 4 there is a good description of what to do when you want
to utilize MEF

[Mindscape "Eventaggregator (including a Bootstrapper with MEF)"](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/2/1/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/). This is built to do  exactly what you are asking for and can be used together with MEF.

Answer (score 0):

It all happens in your [Bootstrapper](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae616b84192450d079cf8b6fb91f0d8b8cda4e6a#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/Bootstrapper.cs). There you can configure your IoC (and/or MEF) to load/compose the views/viewmodels from wherever you want using whatever conventions you want. It provides several useful overridable methods for this puprose. See [this](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper&referringTitle=Documentation) for an example with MEF.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this 10-part series of awesome videos on `PRISM + Unity` which teaches from scratch (what you are asking) - http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/prism--silverlight-part-1-taking-sketched-code-towards-unity.

**NB:** It has nothing to do with Silverlight.

Give it a go !